# How to fit Image into ImageView using Glide library

Tags: android, android-glide

i using glide library to load image. my problem,  image is not getting fit into ImageView. unnecessary spece in **imageview**.

code

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lmeme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

> Image show like this

[image: image show like this]

java code

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(model.getImage()).fitCenter().into(holder.jmeme);
```

Glide library version:
'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

Comment: use `scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lmeme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: @SathishkumarG remove `.fitCenter()`

Comment: sorry. image not load

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lmeme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXy"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```